# Dynamically persistent variable

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I have a function that use 2 persistent variable. The function input is `gcb`, for the actual simulink block. I want to use the function on various block, hence I would like to have the persistent variables declared with a name that makes reference to the block name.

```
function testBlock(blk)
    blkName = get_param(blk, 'name')
    persistent blkValues % this works for one block
    % but I want something like this
    persistent eval([blkName 'Values']) % doesn't work
    ...
end
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `UserData` field on the block?  This would be a much more robust solution.

Comment: @macduff So I would have to do something like `set_param(gcb, 'UserData', [blkName 'Values'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you wanted to do is store the name of the block, then yes.  If you wanted some data and a descriptive name, I would think a structure would work like:

```
data = struct([blkName 'Values'],[]);
set_param(gcb,'UserData',data);
```

Then when you get the data you use,

```
ud = get_param(gcb,'UserData');
% ud.([blkName 'Values']) <- your data
```

Or you could use the global `appdata` storage:

```
setappdata(0,[blkName 'Values'],data);

data = getappdata(0,[blkName 'Values']);
```

Or you could rewrite the function at runtime to create a variable with the name you want, *yick*, but I've seen similar things done.  HTH!

**EDIT**
The `UserData` is the method I have used many times for a dialog callback, so I feel confident that it will work, however I may not completely understand your application. :-)

**EDIT**
If you need the data to persist each time you load the model, then you must set the `UserDataPersistent` parameter to `'on'`.  This is an annoying, but understandably necessary feature to choose whether to forget about what happened after the model is closed and flushed out of memory.  Since this is your use case, `persistent` variables in an m-script will not work since they are forgotten when Matlab terminates.  I believe you would need to use like a [setpref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setpref.html) to get it to persist between Matlab sessions.

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to work with my actual function. I needed persistent variable because the script is in the dialog callback of the mask. So the persistent variable allowed to keep the values between call to the function.

Comment: I used your proposed solution. I found out that I have no choice but to use `set_param(gcb, 'UseDataPersistent', 'on')`. If i don't use it, the UserData is lost when closing and reopening the simulink model. Maybe I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: I thought of that, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to see if this `set_param(gcb,'MaskCallbacks',{...})` could help me replace what I'm actualy trying to achieve with my function.

Answer (score 1):

function with persistent data and reusing that function at different places for different purposes is mutually exclusive. You cannot do both. You have to put your data outside the function. Some ways for doing this are, a)the already suggested UserData field, b)an external file for e.g. a mat file, or c) a container like a map to look up based on the input.